# Rails: Accessing a database not meant for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I have a standard rails application, that uses a mysql database through Active Record, with data loaded through a separate parsing process from a rather large XML file.

This was all well and good, but now I need to load data from an Oracle database, rather than the XML file.

I have no control how the database looks, and only really need a fraction of the data it contains (maybe one or two columns out of a few tables).  As such, what I really want to do is make a call to the database, get data back, and put the data in the appropriate locations in my existing, Rails friendly mysql database.

How would I go about doing this? I've heard* you can (on a model by model basis) specifiy different databases for Rails Models to use, but that sounds like they use them in their entirety, (that is, the database is Rails friendly).  Can I make direct Oracle calls? Is there a process that makes this easier? Can Active Record itself handle this?

A toy example:

If I need to know color, price, and location for an Object, then normally I would parse a huge XML file to get this information.  Now, with oracle, color, price, and location are all in different tables, indexed by some ID (there isn't actually an "Object" table).  I want to pull all this information together into my Rails model.

Edit: Sounds like what I'd heard about was ActiveRecord's "establish_connection" method...and it does indeed seem to assume one model is mapped to one table in the target database, which isn't true in my case.

Edit Edit: Ah, looks like I might be wrong there. "establish_connection" might handle my situation just fine (just gotta get ORACLE working in the first place, and I'll know for sure... If anyone can help, the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396908/problems-using-oracle-with-rails))

Comment: The statement in your edit is incorrect as per my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a connection to Oracle directly and then have ActiveRecord execute a raw SQL statement to query your tables (plural). Off the top of my head, something like this:

```
class OracleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:oracle_development)

  def self.get_objects
    self.find_by_sql("SELECT...")
  end
end
```

With this model you can do `OracleModel.get_objects` which will return a set of records whereby the columns specified in the SELECT SQL statement are attributes of each `OracleModel`. Obviously you can probably come up with a more meaningful model name than I have!

- Create an entry named `:oracle_development` in your `config/database.yml` file with your Oracle database connection details.

Comment: So...you're saying that by executing the raw SQL, I can access tables with names other than the model? Interesting, I'll have to check this out...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. In this case, the model just acts as a class that wraps your SQL statement.

Comment: So, my OracleModel would need to have attributes defined in it's migration for everything I want to pull out of Oracle (even if it's in a variety of different tables in Oracle)?

Comment: No, your `OracleModel` (or whatever you call it) wouldn't need a migration at all. The point is that it exists purely for getting data out of your Oracle database.

Comment: Any tips on getting oracle working in the first place? I have followed a few tutorials, and have the gems "activerecord-oracle_enhanced_adapter" and "ruby-oci8 -v 1.0.4" installed, and oci.dll in the right place (in windows), and I still get runtime errors where the OracleModel type class thinks it doesn't have the active record gem, and also that ruby-oci is too old (but anything newer won't compile for me)

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396908/problems-using-oracle-with-rails  I have. Man, now I"m confused... I thought using Oracle would be the EASY part, and that I just had to worry about dealing with a database that wasn't rails-friendly....

Comment: Yes, that's unfortunate. I've never used Rails with Oracle and I don't use Rails on Windows, so sadly I can't help you that problem. Hopefully someone else can.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it seems to cover you situation pretty well: http://pullmonkey.com/2008/4/21/ruby-on-rails-multiple-database-connections/

It looks like you can make an arbitrarily-named database configuration in the the database.yml file, and then have certain models connect to it like so:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection :arbitrary_database

  #other stuff for your model
end
```

So, the solution would be to make ActiveRecord models for just the tables you want data out of from this other database.  Then, if you really want to get into some sql, use ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).  If you need it as a the actual active_record object, do SomeModel.find_by_sql(sql).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have points enough to edit your question, but it sounds like what you *really* need is to have another "connection pool" available to the second DB  --  I don't think Oracle itself will be a problem.

Then, you need to use these alternate connections to "simply" execute a custom query within the appropriate controller method.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that? Are you saying basically what John Topley says further down? Or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an one-time data conversion or some permanent data exchange between your application and the Oracle database? I think you shouldn't involve Rails in. You could just make a SQL query to the Oracle database, extract the data, and then just insert it into the MySQL database.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure yet, but there's the possibility that I need to load data from Oracle every time a user hits a certain view. Not sure how I would run a completely separate script every time this happens...Ruby can run command line functions, right? Maybe that way?

Comment: I think the suggestion is that if the data in the Oracle DB is static then you could pull it over in one go, outside of Rails. If it changes frequently (i.e. within the day) this wouldn't be an option.

There are ways you could approach it from the Oracle side too (pushing updates out to mySQL or an HTTP call) but you've already confirmed you have no access to modify Oracle DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to *pull* data from your Oracle database, and if you have any ability to add objects to a schema that can see the data you require . . . .

I would simplify things by creating a view on the Oracle table that projects the data you require in a nice friendly shape for ActiveRecord.

This would mean maintaining code to two layers of the application, but I think the gain in clarity on the client-side would outweigh the cost.

You could also use the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Object AS SELECT tab1.*, tab2.* FROM tab1,tab2 syntax so the view returned every column in each table.

If you need to Insert or Update changes to your Rails model, then you need to read up on the restrictions for doing Updates through a view.

(Also, you may need to search on getting Oracle to work with Rails as you will potentially need to install the Oracle client software and additional Ruby modules).

Comment: Er...not quite sure what you mean... I mean, the point of talking to Oracle is to populate an existing MySql database (that already has it's own views all nice and friendly)... Wait. you mean a "view" in the database sense, not in the "Rails" sense. Ah, Okay. I don't know if I can do that... (not familiar with Databases at all, AND I have no access to modifying the database).

Comment: Yes, I meant a database view - think of it as pretty much just a named SELECT statement. Once created it looks exactly like a table to the client. You could use that to create the missing 'Object' table for your Rails model. However, if you have no access to modify the D/B then this is impossible - you'll have to code your custom SQL directly as a custom method.